# Remove element from JSON object by value

Tags: json

I have the next JSON object
console.log:

```
Object {0: "/files/f6/bd/05/a9/medium/f6bd05a970c63b77eae164a607441818.jpeg", 
1: "/files/ff/54/e3/17/medium/ff54e317d47631661eafeec6638ec530.jpeg", 
2: "/files/b3/27/63/17/medium/b3276317020322ef77ac39447075286e.jpeg"}
```

And I need to remove element from this object by this string:

```
/files/f6/bd/05/a9/medium/f6bd05a970c63b77eae164a607441818.jpeg
```

I read a plenty of solutions for this question but all of them was about object with not numeric indexes. I use jQuery for it.
Please help me with function for my trouble. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, first you need a computer, and some programming language to operate it with.

Comment: Damned!! Its my fault. I didnt tell that I operate with JS. Rather with Jquery lib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate through the object to find the value and delete the key once found:

```
// Assuming your object is called "foo":
for ( var k in foo ) {
    if (foo.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
        if (foo[k] === '/files/f6/bd/05/a9/medium/f6bd05a970c63b77eae164a607441818.jpeg') {
            delete foo[k];
        }
    }
}

console.log(foo);
```